# which linux distribution is used in facebook, twitter

Tags: linux, facebook, twitter

I know facebook has done some change. But what's the base?

ubuntu / centos...?

I know google choose ubuntu because of some kind of i/o problem. what about facebook, twitter?

Comment: google choose ubuntu?  that must be a hell of a time machine to make that choice on 1998!!

Comment: I know for a fact that Google has rolled their own.

Answer (score 4):

I'd be surprised if there was "one" simple, homogeneous answer :)

These links might be of interest to you:

http://www.facebook.com/Engineering

http://developers.facebook.com/opensource/

As far as the programming side (this is a programming forum, after all ;)), [this](http://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/interning-at-facebook-coding-inspiration-and-bbqs/10150248537003920?ref=nf) quote is interesting:

> For my first project, I programmed an interactive graph that
>   visualized data center assets. I dove into PHP, XHP, JavaScript, and
>   the glue that Facebook uses to hold them together. I was able to ship
>   code in a few weeks! Now, my mind is bending in a whole new direction,
>   especially while working on backend stuff in C++. Every day I am able
>   to contribute to the Capacity Engineering team and learn a ton,
>   especially from my teammates — awesome!

Finally, [this link](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Facebook-Software-Stack) discusses their software stack, including Linux server (as of 2008).